# How to set default settings in android overlay (captive portal mode)

Tags: settings, overlay, android-source, default-value, android-settings

I am working an aosp project. For this project, I want to set the captive portal check off by default in the aosp build. I figured and tested that I can set the setting via:

```
settings put global captive_portal_detection_enabled 0
```

see also https://www.kuketz-blog.de/android-captive-portal-check-aenderung/

So usually I will set this by using the overlay mechanism for the resources in the device, for example in overlay/frameworks/base/core/packages/settingsprovider/res/value:

```
<resources>
    <!-- disable lockscreen by default to avoid showing of user switcher -->
    <bool name="def_lockscreen_disabled">true</bool>
</resources>
```

I figured, that the default value for the captive portal is in the aosp ConnectivityService defined like

```
        private int getCaptivePortalMode() {
            return Settings.Global.getInt(mContext.getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.Global.CAPTIVE_PORTAL_MODE,
                    Settings.Global.CAPTIVE_PORTAL_MODE_PROMPT);
        }
```

I tried several ways to override it but prepending config_ or _def does not work, adding the entry by

```
<resources>
<!-- disable captive portal checking -->
    <add-resource type="integer" name="config_captive_portal_mode"/>
    <integer name="config_captive_portal_mode">0</integer>
</resources>
```

now I only have 2 options left, but I do not like any of them:
a) patch aosp -> have troubles with updates
b) run a script on the first startup -> ugly

Did I miss something?

Comment: The default value doesn't seem to be customizable through overlays as it's set in Java code. However, you could write an [init script](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/init/README.md) to modify this value on first boot with the adb command you provided: `settings put global captive_portal_detection_enabled 0`. You'd need to add some logic to check whether the device is booting for the first time or not, through a file in userdata for example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the tip. Sad, that there is no "clean" way of doing it.

Comment: I don't understand why you don't want to use the overlay mechanism, it is the correct way to modify the default value of a settings. Why don't you want this way?

Comment: Is there a resource that can be overlaid? The Java code doesn't seem to be importing any and only rely on the `final static int` for the default value. Overlay would definitely be the way to go if the framework was set up this way.

Comment: I agree it would be best to have a supported way to do it as overlay. But since the framework does not support it, we have to use a script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alains answer is what I was looking for.

> You'd need to add some logic to check whether the device is booting
>   for the first time or not, through a file in userdata for example.

Comment: Were you able to set your setting using init script?

Comment: So it worked kind of - but we ended up fixing the issue that demanded that. I still would wish that every setting could be overlayed because this in the end makes the most sense.

Comment: I've tried it manually via adb shell, but I've got a message that settings service is not ready.
I assume the rc script must wait for the ready event from settings service. May be you know on which one?

Answer (score 0):

To add a default value for CAPTIVE_PORTAL_MODE make the below changes in

DatabaseHelper under framework/base/packages/SettingsProvider/src

```
loadIntegerSetting(stmt, Settings.Global.CAPTIVE_PORTAL_MODE,
                    R.integer.def_captive_portal_detection_enabled);
```

Default.xml under framework/base/packages/SettingsProvider/res

```
<integer name="def_captive_portal_detection_enabled" translatable="false">0</integer>
```